# The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed

Tags: certbot

Im working with certbot but I cant install the apache plugin, ill share the commands that i used:

```
# certbot --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed
```

Then I tryed to install it with:

```
#dnf install certbot python3-certbot-apache
dnf install certbot python3-certbot-apache
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository fasttrack is listed more than once in the configuration
Last metadata expiration check: 0:38:45 ago on Sun 08 Oct 2023 06:17:31 PM -04.
Package certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch is already installed.
Package python3-certbot-apache-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Then I check if the plugins is installed:

```
# certbot plugins
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* standalone
Description: Runs an HTTP server locally which serves the necessary validation
files under the /.well-known/acme-challenge/ request path. Suitable if there is
no HTTP server already running. HTTP challenge only (wildcards not supported).
Interfaces: Authenticator, Plugin
Entry point: EntryPoint(name='standalone',
value='certbot._internal.plugins.standalone:Authenticator',
group='certbot.plugins')

* webroot
Description: Saves the necessary validation files to a
.well-known/acme-challenge/ directory within the nominated webroot path. A
seperate HTTP server must be running and serving files from the webroot path.
HTTP challenge only (wildcards not supported).
Interfaces: Authenticator, Plugin
Entry point: EntryPoint(name='webroot',
value='certbot._internal.plugins.webroot:Authenticator',
group='certbot.plugins')
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

but nothing...

```
# certbot --apache
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed
```

I dont know what else do.

Comment: What is the output of `which certbot`?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to install python-certbot-apache

Redhat based distributions:

```
yum install python-certbot-apache
```

Debian based distributions:

```
apt install python-certbot-apache
```